# DataGridComboBoxColumn not showing anything

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagridview, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid in my application which contains two columns. One is name and other is a ComboBox. Now problem I am facing is that in DataGrid only name is shown but ComboBox is not showing up.

Here is my view.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Actions}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedAction}" Header="Actions" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And in my view model.

```
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
}


public IEnumerable<string> Actions
{
    get
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("Action 1");
        list.Add("Action 2");
        return list;
    }
}
```

Now when I add any entry in my GridView I am able to see name, but the ComboxBox column is shown as a textblock. There is no drop down. What is the problem.

Comment: From memory the default behavior is to get a combobox on edit, is your grid editable and have you tried double-clicking a cell?

Comment: Then I would change it and try it then, if you want a combobox all the time you most probably will need to use a DataGridTemplateColumn

Comment: I removed ReadOnly property. It still shown column is textblock. But when I double click column it shows me combo box. But it is empty.

Comment: DataGridTemplateColumn worked. I want to see combo box without double clicking. And DataGridTemplateColumn did that for me. Thanks for your help.